# CLion Debug not working on Mac

Tags: c++, macos, clion

I haven't used CLion in a bit and something is amiss - when I try to debug, breakpoints are not hit. I see the checkmark flash briefly but the program continues to run. Here is a 15 second video showing what happens:

https://youtu.be/txn6W6aSWnM

This project is the vanilla Hello World project with a couple of lines of code added to the main program, and a breakpoint added in the middle.

This is a new Mac - is something misconfigured? Or has something broken in CLion?

Note: This is still happening with 2018.1. I've reported to JetBrains and sent various logs, etc., but still no ability to debug.

Answer (score 2):

I'm using a Mac with the latest version of OSX (10.13.4 as of writing), and also using CLion 2018.1.2. I had this same issue.

The fix was straight forward. Simply go to Tools > CMake > Reset Cache and Reload Project.

Answer (score 1):

ensure the Configuration is the same as the picture[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GVjyh.png)
Simply go to Tools > CMake > Reset Cache and Reload Project.

Comment: Thank you. `Tools > CMake > Reset Cache and Reload Project` worked for me

Answer (score 1):

For anyone who ends up here, I was running `Clion 2018.1.2 on MacOSX Catalina` and had all kinds of problems (specifying GDB vs. LLDB, reseting cache, rebuilding project, etc... nothing worked). `I upgraded to Clion 2020.2.1` and debugged the identical project I was having problems with and BAM; breakpoints, variables, stepping into, etc... all worked.